# Simple MySQL Request Works In phpmyadmin but not php

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a simple SELECT request as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM crumbs WHERE Latitude > '$latmin' AND Latitude < '$latmax' AND Longitude > '$lngmin' AND Longitude < '$lngmax'";
```

Running it in *phpmyadmin* has no issue.

However, when I run the query in php:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Query successful";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

It gives me an error, but only returning the sql variable.

UPDATE: Here's more complete code:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($postdata);

$lat = $data->lat;
$lng = $data->lng;

//using quick and dirty estimate that 111,111 meteres is 1 degree of lat/lng
$variation = 1350/111111;
$latmin = $lat - $variation;
$latmax = $lat + $variation;
$lngmin = $lng - $variation;
$lngmax = $lng + $variation;
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//this will get a rectangle that can contain all possible markers within range
$sql = "SELECT * FROM crumbs WHERE Latitude > '$latmin' AND Latitude < '$latmax' AND Longitude > '$lngmin' AND Longitude < '$lngmax'";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "Query successful";
} else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: what is the error exactly?

Comment: have you check the query string you are generating? that may be the issue if the parameters you are passing are not been replace as expected. Post the error you get too. Good luck.

Comment: print out your $sql to make sure your injected variables are included as you'd expect, if not, try to replace the (') with (`)

Comment: No @Ali, you should not backtick values for queries. It is likely that one or mare of the variables is not correctly set.

Comment: this question is way too unclear. Did you just post and leave?

Comment: *"Simple MySQL Request Works In phpmyadmin but not php"* - You obviously have errors somewhere. We have **no way** of telling what those variables are and what value they hold and the rest of what should have been posted. So, I'm voting to close.

Comment: Not related to your question, but why don't you use `between`? Als I think since `Latitude` and `Longitude` are supposed to be numbers, so you have to remove all single quotes abound your variables...

Comment: Yes I have checked the generated string value - that was the one I used in phpmyadmin. The variables are set correctly. I did not want to give away specific coordinates for privacy purposes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- would you like to take another look?

Comment: echo / var_dump your query to see what it does show for it, then compare it with what you have in your table.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not a novice programmer, stop treating me like one. I'm presenting you with an actual issue, and so far you've just thrown debugging tips at me. Maybe you'd actually like to dig a little deeper and uncover something more complicated going on, or I'll just forget it.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM crumbs WHERE Latitude > ".$latmin." AND Latitude < ".$latmax." AND Longitude > ".$lngmin." AND Longitude < ".$lngmax." ";
```

Hope this one help you.

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Simply concatenating the variables will make no difference here as variables within single quotes (as the OP has done) will be interpolated properly

Comment: Jay Blanchard, you are absolutely right. I am agreed with your concern. But my intention was not to write "try" that you are assuming. Thanks for good advise.

Comment: I am not assuming anything because you wrote "try".